# problems with activity in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter activity that launches another activity with

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Chat()));}
```

from the second activity I launch another activity using the same method

if from the third activity I press the back button it returns to the first activity and if I use

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

it returns to the second activity

how do I make the back button return to the second activity?

Comment: handle the backbutton with WillPopScope

Answer (score 0):

Surround your second and third activities in the following way

```
 WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return false; 
  },
  child: AnotherActivity(
    …
  ),
);
```